# 80 characters per line rule in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How I can implement this rule from Node.js Style Guide:

*80 characters per line
Limit your lines to 80 characters. Yes, screens have gotten much bigger over the last few years, but your brain has not. Use the additional room for split screen, your editor supports that, right?*

To this exemplary JavaScript code below (sorry for this silly question, but I couldn't find straight answer using Google):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var twichApiContainer = [];

  function makeApiLinksReady() {
    var twichtChannels = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas", "sanchowest"];
    var twitchApiZ = "";
    for (var z = 0; z < twichtChannels.length; z++) {
      twitchApiZ = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/' + twichtChannels[z] + '?callback=?';
      twichApiContainer.push(twitchApiZ);
    }
  }

  function useAjaxWithTwich() {
    var twichRequestTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
      $(".container-fluid").html("An error occurred! Application couldn't get Twitch.tv resources!");
    }, 5000); //This is 5 seconds!

    for (var y = 0; y < twichApiContainer.length; y++) {
      $.ajax({
        url: twichApiContainer[y],
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        type: 'GET',
      }).done(function(result) {
        var largeHtml1 = '<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4"><h4>';
        var largeHtml2 = '</h4><div class="well"><div class="row"><div class="row vertical-center"><div class="col-xs-12"><div class="logo">';
        var supplement1 = '<img class="obraz logo-border" src=';
        var supplement2a = result.logo;
        var supplement2b = ' target="_blank">';
        var largeHtml3 = '</div></div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><div class="name">';
        var supplement3a = '<a class="title" href='
        var supplement3b = result.url;
        var supplement3c = ' target="_blank">';
        var supplement3d = result.display_name;
        var supplement4 = '</a>';
        var largeHtml4 = '</div></div></div><hr><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><div class="information">';
        var supplement5 = result.game + ': ' + result.status;
        var largeHtml5 = '</div></div></div></div></div></div>';

        var hugeHtmlSum = largeHtml1 + largeHtml2 + supplement1 + supplement2a + supplement2b + largeHtml3 + supplement3a + supplement3b + supplement3c + supplement3d + supplement4 + largeHtml4 + supplement5 + largeHtml5;
        $(".container-fluid").append(hugeHtmlSum);

        clearTimeout(twichRequestTimeout); //This will prevent timeout from happening!
      });
    }
    return false;
  }

  makeApiLinksReady();
  useAjaxWithTwich();
});
```

```css
.logo {
  text-align: center;
}

.logo-border {
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 0.189rem;
  border-style: solid;
}

.obraz {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 70px;
  max-height: 70px;
}

.name {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.information {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.vertical-center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Twitchtv</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Your text editor doesn't wrap your code for you?

Comment: **@zer00ne** Yes, it does, but when I put it on GitHub it isn't wraped anymore. I thought it should be written with rule 80 characters per line in mind. Shouldn't we use return key or something to do this?

Comment: You just have to add line breaks by pressing `Enter`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you live by the 80 char rule you should also follow these rules:

- **Text you display to the user should not be in your code**

  So that you can easily do i18n
- **HTML should be stored separate from your JavaScript**

  Use some sort of proper templating engine instead. It's safer anyway (xss, etc.)
- Learn how to code before you try to live by rules like that

  - Be consistent with your quoting style (ohh yeah HTML in JavaScript?)
  - Stay up-to-date and code by the current ECMAScript Language Specification
  - jQuery 2 seems so old! People still use that? (IMHO jQuery is a terrible pick anyway - ohh right bootstrap)
  - Proper loops?
  - etc.

When you finally obey those rules use [clang-format](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) to format your code.

It usually does a better job than js-beautify in terms of 80 chars per line rule.

Comment: Thanks, I will follow your hints!